# Leaderboard signin using android basic samples fails with com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4:

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play-games

I am trying to implement Google play games Leaderboards in one of my Android Game made using LibGDX framework .

Trying to implement the basic android samples provided by google at the below repository

https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples

As i am interested in Leaderboards so I am interested in TypeANumber project . As suggested in the github ReadMe.md of this project have done all the settings :

So , i have  done following :

1. setup google play game services for my project
2. Created linked apps and a leaderboard for it
3. Replaces ids in res/ids.xml
4. Change package name in my build.grade of Type-A-Number project 
   applicationId `com.myGame.blah`
5. Compile and run

Executing on my mobile physical device where i am actually logged in for google play games but still when executed .

I do see a button below with message
Sign in with Google to share your scores and achievements with your friends.

When clicked on this button for logged it  , it shows that connecting to the app , but then after some time i get a pop up with error 4:

```
`04-01 17:59:15.604 27814-27814/? D/TanC: signInSilently(): failure
                                         com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4: 
                                             at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzb.zzy(Unknown Source)
                                             at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbk.zzz(Unknown Source)
                                             at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbl.zzr(Unknown Source)
                                             at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzs.zzc(Unknown Source)
                                             at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzs.setResult(Unknown Source)
                                             at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzg.zza(Unknown Source)
                                             at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzt.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method) 04-01 17:59:15.604 27814-27814/? D/TanC: onDisconnected()`
```

Can anyone advice , what am i missing and whats the issue . After searching , i understood may be my Oauth 2.0 client ID is not matching the app , but then i have matched that as well .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Found an official Libgdx sample with Google Play Games Services integration in the [libgdx github repo](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Google-Play-Games-Services-in-LibGDX). This might help you.

Comment: I have checked this already . It says about BaseGameutils which is missing from the repo .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting this error because when we Click on Authorize app after linked app it  shows the default SHA1 of the apk being uploaded at play store , however which is different to the one which we have uploaded so to create it we need to use a keytool command . We should ideally add debug SHA1 certificate as well as the SHA1 certificate using the keystore which we used to generate our release apk .

Below are the commands where C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_72\bin is the path to Java installation in your pc and D:\Java\libGdx\apk\keystore\android.jks is the path to your production keystore

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_72\bin>keytool -list -keystore D:\Java\libGdx\apk\keystore\android.jks
Enter keystore password:
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN
Your keystore contains 1 entry
briskybird, Dec 9, 2017, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 27:XX:XX:XX:XX:B2:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:BD:BF

Use below to generate debug certificate

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_72\bin>keytool -list -keystore C:\Users\USER.android\debug.keystore

C:\Users\.android\debug.keystore is a default path of your debug.keystore and password for debug keystore by default is android

More details can be seen on below link
https://www.versionpb.com/tutorials/step-step-tutorials-libgdx-basic-setup-libgdx/implementing-google-play-services-leaderboards-in-libgdx/